# How can we handle JSON inside JSON with jackson if we are trying to put it inside the hashmap?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to convert JSON object received as a string from a POST request into HashMap.
Everything works fine until i do not put another json inside my base json as below:

```
    {"contextUser": "user",
    "contextPassword": "password",
    "vault": "testVault",
    "type":  "A_Training",
    "name": "crudTest1",
    "revision": "A",
    "policy": "A_Training_Policy",
    "attributeList": {
        "A_Skill": "JAVA",
        "A_Duration": "45",
        "A_CostOfTraining": "1500"
      }
   }
```

Here my base json contains another json inside the key **attributeList** and that additional json is what's creating issue for me.
If I try to hit my REST service's post method using the above JSON it gives me below error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at crud.CRUDController.saveBusDetails(CRUDController.java:78) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]...
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

My post method's relevant code is given below:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            HashMap<String, String> busObjMap = objectMapper.readValue(busData, HashMap.class);
            HashMap<String, String> attributeList = objectMapper.readValue(busObjMap.get("attributeList"), HashMap.class);
            Iterator it=busObjMap.entrySet().iterator();
            System.out.println("Business Object values:");
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> map= (Entry<String, String>) it.next();
                System.out.println(map.getKey()+": "+map.getValue());
            }
            it=attributeList.entrySet().iterator();
            System.out.println("Attribute values:");
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> map= (Entry<String, String>) it.next();
                System.out.println(map.getKey()+": "+map.getValue());
            }
```

Please let me know the correct way to handle such a situation. I'm new to spring.

Comment: i guess the problem is at this line `HashMap<String, String> busObjMap`, change it to `HashMap<String, Object> busObjMap`

Comment: @Deadpool changing it this way gives me the following error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('A' (code 65)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [Source: (String)"{A_Skill=ENOVIA, A_Duration=45, A_CostOfTraining=1500}"; line: 1, column: 3] at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:712) at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:637)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to deserialise inner `JSON Object` one more time. It is already deserialised to `Map` instance. So, all you need is casting.

1. Deserialise payload to `Map<String, Object>` which is safe using `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference` class.
2. Cast inner object to `Map<String, String>` only if `JSON` payload is validated. In other case problem with casting will appear again.
3. To iterate over `Map` do not create `Iterator` object. Use `Java 8` `Stream API` or regular `for` loop.

How code could look like after above changes:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // read as Map
        Map<String, Object> busObjMap = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
        // Inner object is already deserialised as well into Map
        Map<String, String> attributeList = (Map<String, String>) busObjMap.get("attributeList");
        System.out.println("Business Object values:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : busObjMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("Attribute values:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : attributeList.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Create a class matching your json structure, use that instead , it's better in terms of readability.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But my requirements are not as such. I need two hashmaps only.